# Getting Cannot find module 'react-apollo/test-utils' error in jest teact native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, graphql, react-apollo

I am doing unit testing using jest . But getting below error .I tried some solutions but still same . Please suggest me where I am wrong .

FAIL  **tests**/login-test.js
● Test suite failed to run

```
Cannot find module 'react-apollo/test-utils' from 'login-test.js'

  3 | import Login from '../app/components/Login';
  4 | import LoginContainer from '../app/components/container/LoginContainer';
> 5 | import { MockedProvider } from 'react-apollo/test-utils';
    | ^
```

//  package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.9.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.9.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageReporters": [
      "json",
      "html"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jestSetupFile.js",
      "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!react-native|native-base-shoutem-theme|@shoutem/animation|@shoutem/ui|tcomb-form-native|@react-native-community/async-storage|native-base/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons|react-navigation|@codler/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view|react-native-device-info|rn-sliding-up-panel|@react-native-community/masked-view|@react-navigation/bottom-tabs/node_modules/react-native-iphone-x-helper|rn-tooltip|@react-native-community/datetimepicker|node_modules/react-native-tab-view|jsbarcode|@react-native-community/art|@react-native-firebase/analytics|@react-native-firebase|jail-monkey|@dudigital/react-native-zoomable-view/src/ReactNativeZoomableView|@haskkor/react-native-pincode|Platform)"
    ]
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Where is the `react-apollo` in your package.json ? and what version of Apollo Client are you using ?

Comment: @Fraction  "apollo-link-context": "1.0.20",
    "apollo-boost": "0.4.9",
"react-apollo": "3.1.5",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update your import to:

```
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing';
```

From the [Apollo Client 3.0 migration doc](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/migrating/apollo-client-3-migration/#react-apollo):

> `react-apollo` v3 is an umbrella package that re-exports the following
> packages:
>
> - `@apollo/react-common`
> - `@apollo/react-hooks`
> - `@apollo/react-components`
> - `@apollo/react-hoc`
> - `@apollo/react-ssr`
> - `@apollo/react-testing`
>
> The `react-apollo` package has been deprecated, and the functionality
> offered by each of the above packages can now be accessed from
> `@apollo/client` directly:
>
> - `@apollo/react-hooks` -> now available directly from `@apollo/client`
> - `@apollo/react-components` -> now available from `@apollo/client/react/components`
> - `@apollo/react-hoc` -> now available from `@apollo/client/react/hoc`
> - `@apollo/react-ssr` -> now available from `@apollo/client/react/ssr`
> - `@apollo/react-testing` -> now available from `@apollo/client/testing`

Comment: thanks for your time but still same error ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@apollo/client/testing'

Comment: are you sure you have installed @apollo/client ? try `npm install @apollo/client` or `yarn add @apollo/client` if you're using yarn

Comment: its working thanks a lot

Comment: I'm not sure what version of Apollo Client you're using but I'm assuming it's v3 (`@apollo/client`) since you said you're using `react-apollo": "3.1.5"`, but in case you're using v2 (`apollo-client`, which is an old version) you need to install `npm install react-apollo@2.5.8 --save` and keep `import { MockedProvider } from 'react-apollo/test-utils';`